# How to annotate function result based on argument attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets suppose i have the following types

```
import typing

class A:
  pass

class B:
  @property
  def a_factory(self): -> typing.Type[A]
    return A
```

my problem is howto define a type for a callable that takes B instance as argument and return an instance of
the `a_factory` attribute.

What i have so far:

```
C = typing.Callable[[B], ?]
```

I don't want to use A directly because i want the C type to convey the requirement of using B.a_factory factory to produce the return value.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import typing

class A:
    pass

class B:
    @property
    def a_factory(self) -> typing.Type[A]:
        return A

b = B()  # an instance of class B

C = typing.get_type_hints(B.a_factory.fget)["return"]
C = typing.get_type_hints(b.__class__.a_factory.fget)["return"]
print(C)  # typing.Type[__main__.A]
```

- Maybe a property is not simply a callable; since the code above only defines getter of property, so we need `fget` to retrive the getter function, then use `get_type_hints` to get returned type.
- To retrive the class `B` from instance `b`, we need `__class__` attribute.